# How to test concurrency locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency

Whats the best way to test concurrency locally?  i.e. i want to test 10 concurrent hits. I am aware of services like [Blitz](http://blitz.io/). However, I am trying to find a simpler way of doing it locally to test against race conditions.

Any ideas? Via Curl maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Apache Bench ([`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)).  Basic usage is dead simple:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://your.application
```

Answer (score 0):

For locally testing race conditions in the tests you can use helpers like this

```
# call block in a forked process
def fork_with_new_connection(config, object = nil, options={})
  raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
  options = {
     :stop => true, :index => 0
  }.merge(options)

  fork do
    # stop the process after fork
    Signal.trap('STOP') if options[:stop]
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
      yield(object)
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
    end
  end
end

# call multiply times blocks
def multi_times_call_in_fork(count=3, &block)
  raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
  config = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
  pids = []
  count.times do |index|
    pids << fork_with_new_connection(config, nil, :index=>index, &block)
  end

  # continue forked processes
  Process.kill("CONT", *pids)

  Process.waitall
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
end

# example
multi_times_call_in_fork(5)  do
  # do something with race conditions
  # add asserts 
end
```